# Cloning Postgres schema/tables across multiple servers

Tags: postgresql, schema

I'm working on a project that has databases across multiple servers, with one server for each business client.  The project has some identical 'base' tables that are present in all the databases (for example, profiles, groups, etc), but each database also has some tables that are specific to that client.  I'd like to be able alter/add columns in the base tables without having to manually do it for each database.  We're currently working with 6 clients, so every time we add a new feature that requires me to add a column I have to manually add the column to 6 different databases.  Obviously, this does not scale well.

Is there a tool that allows for changes to a base table to be replicated across an arbitrary number of databases/servers?  Thanks.

Edit: For clarification, each base table is independent to each client, because those base tables exist on the server that is specific to that client.

Comment: Hello Jason, is each base table also independent to each client or can those base tables exist solely on one server?

Comment: OP: Please merge your accounts.

Comment: symmetricds might do what you want. can sync schema changes over network, filter for diff clients.